# Adding to a WAV file in Python

Tags: python, numpy, audio, stream, wav

I want to add to a wav file, ideal would be from a numpy array. I tried the following code:

```
data = stream.read(CHUNK)
audio_numpy = numpy.frombuffer(data, dtype=numpy.int16)
scipy.io.wavfile.write(FILENAME, RATE, audio_numpy)
```

where stream is created by

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
```

as I heard that scipy would add to the file and not overwrite it. Unfortunately however, it overwrites the file. 
How can I append to a WAV file? The input comes from the microphone.
The WAV file should be accessed from ffmpeg later, so that the WAV file should not be written in total again, as this is also inefficient.